# How to convert a string to a decimal exactly and vice versa

Tags: php

I want to start off by saying that I'm sorry if this question has already been asked- I looked around and there was nothing that matched my query. Basically I want to know how to convert the string "100.0" or "100." to the floats 100.0 and 100.0 and also how to make sure the floats 100.0 and 100. don't equal each other (the same goes for situations like 100. and 100 and 100.0 and 100 Thanks!

Edit: To clarify the not equaling thing here's an example:

Let's say you have a variable `$a = 100.` and `$b = 100.0`  I want to make sure $a doesn't equal $b

Comment: This part of your question makes no sense: "and also how to make sure the floats 100.0 and 100. don't equal themselves"; any variable will always equal itself, and 100 and 100.0 are the same number, so will always equal *each other* as well. If you want to compare the strings, you'll need to do so before converting them to numbers.

Comment: There is only one `100` in a floating point representation.

Comment: It's impossible. The physical representation of a float number is the same.

Comment: @IMSoP sorry let me clarify that. Let's say you have a variable $a = 100. and $b = 100.0  I want to make sure $a doesn't equal $b

Comment: You will need to compare them as strings not numbers

Comment: @scrowler thanks, that's probably what I'll end up doing.

Comment: @Kpower You can't. They *are* equal. That's not PHP, that's basic maths.

Comment: @IMSoP in physics with sig figs (which i'm working with) they're different

Comment: @Kpower Well, they're of equal value, but distinct uncertainty, I guess. A general purpose programming language will rarely preserve that "uncertainty" attribute, although there are probably specialist languages and libraries that let you do so.

Comment: Either way, thanks @IMSoP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined `$a` and `$b` like:

```
$a = 100;
$b = 100.0;
```

.. then they aren't the same. `$a` is an `integer` and `$b` is a `float`. You can see this using:

```
var_dump($a, $b);
```

But however, as they both are numerice types, you need to compare them using the `strict comparison operator` `===`:

```
if($a === $b) {
    echo "equal";
} else {
    echo "not equal";
}
```

---

If you have them defined as strings:

```
$a = "100";
$b = "100.0";
```

then even the simple equal operator `==`  would work:

```
if($a == $b) {
    echo "equal";
} else {
    echo "not equal";
}
```